# zapier-platform-cli init Error! ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, integration, zapier

Just starting with a Zapier Integration development using zapier-platform-cli, though after a simple `zapier init zapp` I am getting the following output:

```
Error! ENOENT: no such file or directory, open C:\Users\USERNAME:\Users\username1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-286764LYpWKGFgiNI\zapier-template.zip'
```

It seems that the command is trying to access a wrong path. I am using Windows 7 and this seems to be a reported/open issue in the repository [zapier-platform-cli issue](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli/issues/1).

So, just trying to know if someone has any thoughts or idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with the `TMP` Environment variable.

I have solved the problem setting up the variable to `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp`

Also, I did the same to `TEMP` variable as it is used instead of `TMP` in some situations.

As I am using Powershell I have made it permanent by adding to my Powershell profile (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) the following lines:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue as you correctly pointed out https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli/issues/1.

It might be related to underlying zip libraries but we've not had the chance to test it.

Have you tried `zapier build --debug` and pasting the traceback on the issue as a comment?